# Camera View on SurfaceView Overlap

Tags: android, surfaceview

I'm trying to create a camera view on *SurfaceView*, it's placed in a dialog with *ScrollView*. But the camera view overlaps the layout before scrolling is done. I have tried some solutions but still can't overcome this issue. I was thought it gonna be solved just by do something like bring to the front the base layout or send to back the camera view which is *SurfaceView*, but it still can't solve the issue.
This is my code:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        int width2 = (int) (0.82 * width);
        int width3 = (int) (0.82 * width);
        
        LinearLayout lay = uiExtTools.baselayout(context);  
        
        RelativeLayout relativeParent = new RelativeLayout(context);
        relativeParent.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                width3,
                width2));
        relativeParent.setPadding(20,20,20,5);


        SurfaceView cameraView = new SurfaceView(context);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
       
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        cameraView.setLayoutParams(params);
        cameraView.setPadding(20,20,20,20);

        relativeParent.addView(cameraView);

        lay.addView(relativeParent);

        BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(context)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.ALL_FORMATS)
                .build();
        CameraSource cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(context,barcodeDetector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1600,1024)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .build();
        cameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try {
                    cameraSource.start(cameraView.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });
```

here I attached my screen layout:
[image: here I attached my screen layout:]

Any helps or suggestions would be great

**EDIT:**
Here I attached the screen layout after scrolling is done too:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use SurfaceView if the Layout is not ALWAYS COMPLETLY visible because, as it is written in reference page (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView): "*the SurfaceView punches a hole in its window to allow its surface to be displayed*".

You have to use TextureView (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView) but it could require many changes....